# one abstract class(superclass),two subclass, one implementation in one subclass. is it legal?

Tags: java

Is it really necessary to implement all the methods to a subclass(inherited from a abstract class), if there is another subclass of that abstract class has already implemented those abstract methods?

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void method();
    abstract void anothermethod();
}

class B extends A {   
    void method() {}
    void anothermethod() {}    
}

class C extends A { // is this class definition is legal?
    void sample() {}    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not legal. You've got a *concrete* class (`C` is not declared abstract) extending an abstract class, but without providing implementations for its methods. It's not really clear why you think this *should* or *could* be legal - and you should consider whether this has wider ramifications for your understanding of inheritance in general than just this specific case.

`C` is entirely separate from `B`. They could have entirely different state - for example, B might implement `method()` using some state which is only present in an instance of `B`. It's important to understand that an instance of `C` is *not* an instance of `B`.

If you want it to inherit its behaviour, you should make `C` subclass `B` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Only if you mark C as an abstract class. Therefore passing on its implementation responsibilities to it's subclasses.

Another option would be to have C extend B, and therefore B would contain the implementation demanded of A by its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

No. Class C will be abstract in this case, too.

What about `class C extends B`?

Answer (score 0):

Thats absolutely illegal unless you make the class "C" abstract as IronBlossom suggested or implements all the abstract method of class "A"in class "C".